# Cannot import Oracle dump: IMP-00033: Warning: Table not found in export file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-dump

I have an Oracle dump (.dmp) that I want to import into my local Oracle instance. But when I do a full import, it fails with

> IMP-00033: Warning: Table not found in export file.

Some facts:

- using `imp system/pass ignore=yes tables=(t1,t2,t3,..)`
- export is successful (according to log)
- export is done in Oracle Database 10g Release 10.1.0.4.0, import is done in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0
- when I do `show=y` DDL is shown for all the tables on the list
- before printing the 00033 warning, there is `IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file`
- when I do a full import (without specifying table names), there are all sorts of errors, including

  > "IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1435 encountered",
  >  
  >   "ORA-01435: user does not exist", 
  >   "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges".

These errors do not appear when I specify the table names.

How to do the import?

Comment: Any specific reason to use `IMP` instead of data pump(`IMPDP`)?

Comment: What were the export parameters? Who owns the table? Looks like you need to specify fromuser/touser but not sure...

Comment: the export was done via exp (I think), so I have to use imp. The export is outside of my control, it's a standard procedure in another 'body'.
I'll ask for the export params

Comment: export command:

exp system/... FULL=Y buffer=300000 FILE=/tmp/$FILE LOG=/tmp/$FILE.log


nothing extraordinary..

Comment: Not sure why you'd get ORA-01031 on full import then. But to change to a table-evel import you'd need to specify which user owns the table, with fromuser/touser - since they won't be owned by `system` (hopefully!). It's so long since I used original exp/imp I'm not 100% sure what else you might need, but try just specifying those. I assume you know the new and old schema names (from the log, at least).

Answer (score 1):

If you got `IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file`  this probably means that the import file do not have the expected format, or worse that it is incomplete! (but in that last case you would not be able to import specifying table names).

Since the database versions are so different, you should make sure that your import script specifies the format of incoming data with `version=10.1.0` in your `imp` command